# How to forward data from desktop application through fiddler or mitmproxy?

Tags: tcp, proxy, windows-10, fiddler, mitmproxy

I am using a win10 desktop app for which I know it is sending TCP packets in order to communicate with the server. The payloads are encrypted. There is a chance that if the app is using TLS, a proxy like mitmproxy or fiddler will be able to decrypt the data.

The app also gets assigned different port every time it launches. So far the only promising information was to use netsh:
`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=appPort listenaddress=appLocalIP connectport=fiddlerListeningPort connectaddress=fiddlerLocalIP`

I ran this command after the app was already running because I can not determine its local port beforehand. But that did nothing. I was unable to find any other way to force the app to route the traffic through fiddler / mitmproxy.